# My Express 4.13.1 app listens on 2 different ports

Tags: node.js, express

I encountered something weird. Probably because I'm new to Express and Node.

I'm using Express 4.13.1 and by default it runs on port 3000.

However, when I added this line to my app.js:

`app.listen(8080);`

The app started to listen on both port 3000 and 8080.
The console output is:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=62380 --nolazy bin/www
Debugger listening on port 62380
Mon, 16 Nov 2015 13:59:13 GMT chatDel:server Listening on port 3000
```

But to be clear, requests on both ports responded.

What am I missing?

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var config = require('./config/serverConfig');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var inmsg = require('./routes/inmsg');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/inmsg', inmsg);
app.listen(8080);


var connection =             mongoose.createConnection(config.mongoose.connectionString);
global.db = connection;
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

//load all files in model dir
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function(filename){
  if(~filename.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/models/' + filename);
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my Package.jason:

```
{
  "name": "chatDel",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.13.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
"debug": "~2.2.0",
"express": "~4.13.1",
"indicative": "^1.3.1",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"mongodb": "~3.0.7",
"mongoose": "^4.2.4",
"mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",
"morgan": "~1.6.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
"stately.js": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I took some more action:

1. I restarted my computer
2. I made sure that no "node" processes are alive
3. I started Debug from my IDE again
4. Again, both ports are available (8080 and 3000) and only 1 "node" process is visible in the process list of my computer.(I'm using macbook pro)

When i changed the line that listens to the port to be: app.listen(3000) i got the following error upon Debug in my console: (Again, only 1 node process was visible and then it quit after about 10 sec from the error.)

> /usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=49558 --nolazy bin/www
>   Debugger listening on port 49558
>   Port 3000 is already in use
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**EDIT 2:**
Here is my www file which is located under /bin/www it has no extension although it is a js file and it was generated as part of the installation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('chatDel:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: So, the debugger is listening on 62380 and the web server itself is on 3000. What's the problem? 8080 port should not respond at this time. Show us the server code so we can check.

Comment: Have you made sure that no older instances are running from before you changed the code to port 8080?

Comment: Yes i have, when i stop the server nothing is listening, and when i start it in debug mode, both ports are available. I'll add some server code right now.

Comment: btw, I'm using Webstorm 11 as an IDE. And node 4.2.2

Comment: You have app.listen(8080) in there, so that explains 8080.  Are you sure the 3000 isn't just a leftover logging statement in one of your requires or something?

Comment: @AlexT I'm sure. I'm going to add some more details to my question now. I have restarted my computer and verified that no "node" process are running. Then i run the process in debug from my IDE and and the same happened - both ports are listening to requests on the server.

Comment: Wait.  What is in /bin/www/index.js ? Noticed your run command doesn't actually run app.js

Comment: I have bin/www and not bin/www/index.js. www is a JS file with no extension. (Default Express installation)
I have the following lines inside which probably are the root cause:
`var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');`
`app.set('port', port);`

I will add the entire file to my question

Comment: @AlexT Also, i have looked for the string 3000 in my entire project inside all JS files, but since www has no extension, it was overlooked ;)

Comment: @AlexT Please post an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much in helping me figure that one up.
 I deleted the `app.listen` from app.js and altered `normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');` into `normalizePort(process.env.PORT || config.port);` inside the `www` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment thread - check your /bin/www rather than app.js. :)

Comment: Can you please shade some more light on the www file? any kind of info will do. Also, from my mistake we have learned how to make an app listen on 2 different ports :) so, does it have any benefits in terms of server performance? (Please add that to your answer and not in the comments)